# Euler's formula simplification

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I have been trying to simplify this expression:

$$\cos (\theta) - \frac{1}{\cos (\theta) + i \sin(\theta)}$$

into:

$$\ i \sin(\theta).$$

However I can't find what steps to take to get to this simplification.

Euler's formula states:

$$\ e^{i\theta}= \cos (\theta) + i \sin(\theta) $$

It is linked to this formula however I am not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$cos(\theta)-\frac{1}{\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)}=cos(\theta)-\frac{1}{e^{i\theta}}=$$
$$cos(\theta)-e^{-i\theta}=\frac{1}{2}e^{i\theta}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}e^{i\theta}-\frac{1}{2}e^{-i\theta}=i\Big(\frac{1}{2i}e^{i\theta}-\frac{1}{2i}e^{-i\theta}\Big)=i\sin(\theta)$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$e^{-i\theta}=\cos(-\theta)+i\sin(-\theta)=\cos\theta-i\sin\theta$$

$$\implies\cos\theta-i\sin\theta=\dfrac1{\cos\theta+i\sin\theta}$$ which is also evident from $(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)(\cos\theta-i\sin\theta)=\cdots=1$

Answer (score 0):

Solving a more general problem, if $\space\exists\space\text{z}\in\mathbb{C}$:

$$\mathcal{Z}:=\Re\left(\text{z}\right)-\frac{1}{\text{z}}=\Re\left(\text{z}\right)-\frac{\overline{\text{z}}}{\text{z}\cdot\overline{\text{z}}}=\Re\left(\text{z}\right)-\frac{\overline{\text{z}}}{\left|\text{z}\right|^2}=\Re\left(\text{z}\right)-\frac{\Re\left(\text{z}\right)-\Im\left(\text{z}\right)i}{\Re^2\left(\text{z}\right)+\Im^2\left(\text{z}\right)}\tag1$$

So, we get:

$$\mathcal{Z}=\frac{\Re\left(\text{z}\right)\left(\Re^2\left(\text{z}\right)+\Im^2\left(\text{z}\right)\right)}{\Re^2\left(\text{z}\right)+\Im^2\left(\text{z}\right)}-\frac{\Re\left(\text{z}\right)-\Im\left(\text{z}\right)i}{\Re^2\left(\text{z}\right)+\Im^2\left(\text{z}\right)}=$$
$$\frac{\Re\left(\text{z}\right)\left(\Re^2\left(\text{z}\right)+\Im^2\left(\text{z}\right)\right)-\Re\left(\text{z}\right)+\Im\left(\text{z}\right)i}{\Re^2\left(\text{z}\right)+\Im^2\left(\text{z}\right)}\tag2$$

Now, when $\Re\left(\text{z}\right)=\cos\theta$ and $\Im\left(\text{z}\right)=\sin\theta$:

$$\Re^2\left(\text{z}\right)+\Im^2\left(\text{z}\right)=\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1\tag3$$

So:

$$\mathcal{Z}=\frac{\cos\theta-\cos\theta+i\sin\theta}{1}=i\sin\theta\tag4$$